# Is there the CommandLineToArgvA function in windows c/c++ (VS 2022)?

Tags: c++, c, windows

There is the `CommandLineToArgvW()` function, which is `CommandLineToArgv` + `W`, where this `W` means wide char (`wchar_t` in C/C++). But the `CommandLineToArgvA()` function that should exist, such as `GetCommandLineW()` and `GetCommandLineA()`, does not exist, apparently.

char:

```c
int argv;
char **argv = CommandLineToArgvA(GetCommandLineA(), &argc);
```

wide char:

```c
int argv;
wchar_t **wargv = CommandLineToArgvW(GetCommandLineW(), &argc);
```

Well, I searched every corner of the Internet for the term `CommandLineToArgvA()` and the most I found was this function in Linux Wine... I want to know, does this function exist, and if yes, is it normal that it is "hidden"? Otherwise, does it really not exist?

edit: The question was whether there was the `CommandLineToArgvA` function in the Windows API, however, it does not exist (comment by Remy Lebeau). The answer I checked as correct is the one that best explains how to use the existing `CommandLineToArgvW` function and turn the `wchar_t` into `char`, which will provide the same result that would be provided with the `CommandLineToArgvA` function if it existed.

Comment: No, there is not. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: There has never been an ANSI-based `CommandLineToArgvA` in the Windows API.  But it is fairly trivial to write one yourself, either by converting to Unicode and using `CommandLineToArgvW`, or by parsing the string yourself using the rules outlined in [Argument Definitions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/88w63h9k(v=vs.85)) and [Parsing C++ Command-Line Arguments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/17w5ykft(v=vs.85)).

Comment: One could probably also find the function that the C Runtime Library uses (when your entrypoint is named `main(int argc, char** argv)`)... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/getmainargs-wgetmainargs

Comment: See [Chapter 10.8](https://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/notes/sx10h.html) in [these course notes](https://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/notes).

Comment: Why do you want this?  Is your code not Unicode-aware?

Comment: I wonder what could be the reason behind Microsoft deciding not to provide an ANSI version for this particular function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don’t think you should try parsing your own command-line string. Windows does it one way. Trying to write duplicate code to do the same thing is the Wrong Thing™ to do.

Just get the command-line, then use the Window facilities to convert it to UTF-8.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <shellapi.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "Shell32")

void get_command_line_args( int * argc, char *** argv )
{
  // Get the command line arguments as wchar_t strings
  wchar_t ** wargv = CommandLineToArgvW( GetCommandLineW(), argc );
  if (!wargv) { *argc = 0; *argv = NULL; return; }
  
  // Count the number of bytes necessary to store the UTF-8 versions of those strings
  int n = 0;
  for (int i = 0;  i < *argc;  i++)
    n += WideCharToMultiByte( CP_UTF8, 0, wargv[i], -1, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL ) + 1;
  
  // Allocate the argv[] array + all the UTF-8 strings
  *argv = malloc( (*argc + 1) * sizeof(char *) + n );
  if (!*argv) { *argc = 0; return; }
  
  // Convert all wargv[] --> argv[]
  char * arg = (char *)&((*argv)[*argc + 1]);
  for (int i = 0;  i < *argc;  i++)
  {
    (*argv)[i] = arg;
    arg += WideCharToMultiByte( CP_UTF8, 0, wargv[i], -1, arg, n, NULL, NULL ) + 1;
  }
  (*argv)[*argc] = NULL;
}
```

Obtains an `argv` just like the one `main()` gets, with a final `NULL` element
and writeable and all.

Interface is easy enough. Don’t forget to `free()` the result when you are done with it. Example usage:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void f(void)
{
  int     argc;
  char ** argv;
  get_command_line_args( &argc, &argv );
  
  for (int n = 0;  n < argc;  n++)
    printf( "  %d : %s\n", n, argv[n] );
  
  free( argv );
}

int main(void)
{
  f();
}
```

Enjoy!